# SynthesisToFile not Working

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm using synthesis To file to write in external storage .but  i found exception on file not found error.i'm unable to read file from the sdcard. How to store in external device?

Comment: Would you mind to share your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please declare this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: i have used    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
       <uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" /> but it is not working

Comment: and i'm using the emulator not device.

Comment: thank you @vinil. I have cleared the problem. i havent add memory card storage space in emulator..

Comment: Oh.. For further queries you can contact me always